# Get YouTube video thumbnail and use it with PHP

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, video-thumbnails

How can I access thumbnail collection of a YouTube video using the link of the video from the YouTube API.
I want thumbnails to be displayed on website using PHP using the video id stored in a variable for example `$link`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

YouTube stores many different types of thumbnails on its server for different devices. You can access it by using the video id which 
every YouTube video has. You can display the images on your website using a variable `$link` which holds the id of the video and substituting it
in the place for video_ID in the link.

Low quality thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/sddefault.jpg
```

Medium quality thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/mqdefault.jpg
```

High quality thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/hqdefault.jpg
```

Maximum quality thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<YouTube_Video_ID_HERE>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

**Example:**

If you want to access the thumbnail of the following video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-GYwhqDo6o
```

Video ID :   `Q-GYwhqDo6o`

So, this is how video thumbnail link looks like:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/Q-GYwhqDo6o/mqdefault.jpg
```

Hope it helps. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 16):

To get high-quality image you can use the following URL which is fetched from youtube API

```
$video_id = explode("?v=", $link);
$video_id = $video_id[1];
$thumbnail="http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$video_id."/maxresdefault.jpg";
```

Comment: The best quality from all the answers... Thanks buddy.

Comment: this doesn't work with `youtu.be` kind of urls since they ommit the `?v=`

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo It is working for almost all videos.

Comment: @Rishi exactly, 'almost', you cannot explode a `youtu.be/<video_id>` url with `explode("?v=", $link);`  

Advice: use `alaouy/youtube` library. It manages urls, ids, and communicate with the Youtube Api v.3 providing you a lot of video info.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the below code. It is work for me. Choose the image quality as per your requirement.

```
<?php
$youtubeID = getYouTubeVideoId('youtube video url');
$thumbURL = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $youtubeID . '/mqdefault.jpg';
print_r($thumbURL);

function getYouTubeVideoId($pageVideUrl) {
    $link = $pageVideUrl;
    $video_id = explode("?v=", $link);
    if (!isset($video_id[1])) {
        $video_id = explode("youtu.be/", $link);
    }
    $youtubeID = $video_id[1];
    if (empty($video_id[1])) $video_id = explode("/v/", $link);
    $video_id = explode("&", $video_id[1]);
    $youtubeVideoID = $video_id[0];
    if ($youtubeVideoID) {
        return $youtubeVideoID;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Great i just created helper function with this, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

here is my handy function to download the Youtube thumbnail image

```
function downloadYouTubeThubnailImage($youTubeLink='',$thumbNamilQuality='',$fileNameWithExt='',$fileDownLoadPath='')
    {
        $videoIdExploded = explode('?v=', $youTubeLink);   

        if ( sizeof($videoIdExploded) == 1) 
        {
            $videoIdExploded = explode('&v=', $youTubeLink);

            $videoIdEnd = end($videoIdExploded);

            $removeOtherInVideoIdExploded = explode('&',$videoIdEnd);

            $youTubeVideoId = current($removeOtherInVideoIdExploded);
        }else{
            $videoIdExploded = explode('?v=', $youTubeLink);

            $videoIdEnd = end($videoIdExploded);

            $removeOtherInVideoIdExploded = explode('&',$videoIdEnd);

            $youTubeVideoId = current($removeOtherInVideoIdExploded);
        }

        switch ($thumbNamilQuality) 
        {
            case 'LOW':
                    $imageUrl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youTubeVideoId.'/sddefault.jpg';
                break;

            case 'MEDIUM':
                    $imageUrl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youTubeVideoId.'/mqdefault.jpg';
                break;

            case 'HIGH':
                    $imageUrl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youTubeVideoId.'/hqdefault.jpg';
                break;

            case 'MAXIMUM':
                    $imageUrl = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youTubeVideoId.'/maxresdefault.jpg';
                break;
            default:
                return  'Choose The Quality Between [ LOW (or) MEDIUM  (or) HIGH  (or)  MAXIMUM]';
                break;
        }  

        if( empty($fileNameWithExt) || is_null($fileNameWithExt)  || $fileNameWithExt === '') 
        {
            $toArray = explode('/',$imageUrl);
            $fileNameWithExt = md5( time().mt_rand( 1,10 ) ).'.'.substr(strrchr(end($toArray),'.'),1);
          }

          if (! is_dir($fileDownLoadPath)) 
            {
                mkdir($fileDownLoadPath,0777,true);
            }

            file_put_contents($fileDownLoadPath.$fileNameWithExt, file_get_contents($imageUrl));
            return $fileNameWithExt;   
    }
```

`Function Description`

Argumemts

**`$youTubeLink`**  Youtube url **`for example`**  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3ICNMQW7Ok`

**`$thumbNamilQuality`**  It has Many Quality Such as **`LOW ,MEDIUM, HIGH, MAXIMUM`**

Thumbnail Quality list Taken from 
**https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346348/8487424**

&& 
 **https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546113/8487424**

**`$fileNameWithExt`**  File Name with Extension**`for example`**  `myfavouriteimage.png`

> NOTE  `$fileNameWithExt` is not mandatory  it will generate the `uuid` based file name
>   for `Example` `91b2a30d0682058ebda8d71606f5e327.jpg`

if you want to put the file to the custom directory use this argument

> NOTE  `$fileDownLoadPath` is not mandatory  it will generate the image file where the script is executing

Some of the sample examples

```
$folderpath = 'c:'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'xampp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'htdocs'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'youtube'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$imageName = 'mybeautfulpic.jpg';

downloadYouTubeThubnailImage('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3ICNMQW7Ok','MAXIMUM',null,$folderpath );

downloadYouTubeThubnailImage('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3ICNMQW7Ok','LOW',$imageName ,null);
```

Hope it is answered already but this function has `some exta features`

Answer (score 1):

Google changed API on v.3 and those code from Python work exactly! You can use for PHP.

```
def get_small_image_url(self):
    return 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/%s.jpg' % (self.video_id, random.randint(1, 3))

def get_hqdefault(self):
    return 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/%s/hqdefault.jpg' % self.video_id

def get_mqdefault(self):
    return 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/%s/mqdefault.jpg' % self.video_id

def get_sddefault(self):
    return 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/%s/sddefault.jpg' % self.video_id

def get_video_id(self, url):
    link = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if link.hostname == 'youtu.be':
        return link.path[1:]
    if link.hostname in ('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com'):
        if link.path == '/watch':
            state = urlparse.parse_qs(link.query)
            return state['v'][0]
        if link.path[:7] == '/embed/':
            return link.path.split('/')[2]
        if link.path[:3] == '/v/':
            return link.path.split('/')[2]
    return False

def get_meta(self, video_id):
    api_token = **'here your API_Token'**
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=%s&key=%s' % (video_id, api_token)
    response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    print response
    context = {
        'title': response['items'][0]['snippet']['localized']['title'],
        'desc': response['items'][0]['snippet']['localized']['description']
    }
    return context

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    video_id = self.get_video_id(self.url)
    meta = self.get_meta(video_id)
    self.video_id = video_id
    self.title = meta['title']
    self.description = meta['desc']
    super(Videos, self).save(
        force_insert=force_insert,
        force_update=force_update,
        using=using,
        update_fields=update_fields
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest and easiest way to get youtube-video-id from a youtube link using **str_replace**.

```
$youtube_ids = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBKdaUv5YaI");
echo 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_ids.'/maxresdefault.jpg';
```

Low-quality thumbnail:

```
echo 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_ids.'/sddefault.jpg';
```

Medium quality thumbnail:

```
echo 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_ids.'/mqdefault.jpg';
```

High quality thumbnail:

```
echo 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_ids.'/hqdefault.jpg';
```

Maximum quality thumbnail:

```
echo 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube_ids.'/maxresdefault.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2 cents.
I prefer to store the image preview on my server. A draft of the code that I use is:

```
// from and destination sources
$src_yt     = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$ytcode/mqdefault.jpg";               // file on youtube
$dest       = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/video/$prevtype/$ytcode.jpg";     // destination

/* Add notice for success/failure */
if( !copy( $src_yt, $dest ) ) {
    echo "ALT! failed to copy $src_yt...\n";
}
else {
    echo "OK! success to copy $src_yt...\n";
}
```